# Is there a way to right click Junk mail folder in Thunderbird and empty it, just like with the trash folder?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I would like to right click on the junk folder and empty it completely without having to click one of the messages and do a "Ctrl + A". Is this possible?

(I tried [Keyconfig](https://superuser.com/questions/201601/thunderbird-delete-all-junk-mails-at-once), but Thunderbird started hanging, so I disabled it.)

Answer (score 1):

Current Thunderbird version has menu to emptying Junk Folder too. In my PC, I has Thunderbird version 31.6.0.

Just right click "Junk" Folder and click "Empty Junk".

[image: Empty Junk]

Comment: Huh. It only does that with Outlook and Gmail messages, but not Yahoo. Do you know if there is a way to change the "type" of a folder? Thunderbird imports Yahoo's junk folder as a folder called "Bulk Mail", which isn't designated as the account's junk folder.

Comment: Nevermind. I think I got it. To any future visitors, you need to activate a "Junk" folder for the account. Look for something called "Junk Settings" in your Account Settings. [Here's](http://my.science.oregonstate.edu/selfhelp/thunderbird-junk) a link with specifics.